# How to create hibernate entity manager using java.sql.Connection

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I want to create Hibernate entity manager using java.sql.Connection object, with out persistence unit, Is there any way to achieve this?

The scenario is my application uses Hibernate, in a flow we will call a independent Java program which returns a connection object, i have to use the same connection to persist the transaction.

Comment: How are you getting a connection from an "independent Java program"? Connection object is not something you can pass from one JVM to another.

Comment: Its an independent program, which will return a plain connection object. I have to re sue the same connection

Comment: Is this independent as in "running in a separate JVM" or independent as in "this is a bunch of other people's code that I can call via the only exposed public method"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own plugin strategy for obtaining JDBC connections by implementing the interface [org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/connection/ConnectionProvider.html), and specifying your custom implementation via the hibernate.connection.provider_class property.